# "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy creando una "Lista de tareas" pero me sale este error:

> "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops"

Este es mi código:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import List from './Components/List';
import TaskForm from './Components/TaskForm';

import TaskList from './Sample/TaskList.json'
class App extends React.Component{
  
  state = {
    taskLists: TaskList
  }
  
  addTask = (title,description) => {
    const newTask = {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      id: this.state.taskLists.length
    }
    this.setState({
      taskLists : [...this.state.taskLists, newTask]
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TaskForm addTask={this.addTask} />
        <List tasks={this.state.taskLists} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Apareció cuando agregué esta parte de código:

```
this.setState({
      taskLists : [...this.state.taskLists, newTask]
    })
```

Comment: Revisa este enlace a ver si algunas de las respuesta con el mismo titulo te funciona: [es.stackoverflow?error-maximum-update-depth-exceeded](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=error-maximum-update-depth-exceeded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes utilizar state.taskLists como referencia para modificar state.taskLists mediante setState, produciendo una actializacion en loop.

Si deseas usar el valor anterior usa el formato de funcion y el estado previo referenciado:

```
this.setState( prevState) => ({
      taskLists : [...prevState.taskLists, newTask]
    })
)
```